# Gauss-Markov theorem

Tags: statistics, regression

Is it true that in the classical simple linear regression model with no intercept term, an instrumental variables estimator $\beta_{IV}$ that uses $Z_i= X_i- \bar X$ as an instrumental variable for $X_i$ will generally be inferior to the LS estimator $\beta_\text{LS}$ by the Gauss-Markov theorem?

Comment: At this hour I'm not going to deal with this.  Maybe tomorrow...... But possibly also this might fare better at stats (dot) stackexchange (dot) com, even though it's a purely mathematical question. $\qquad$